# SyntaxError: unexpected token else (I can not find the error in my code)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error an I don't know what I did wrong. I have narrowed the possible error to this code but it gets hazy of exactly were it is after that. I a pretty sure it has something to do with the last else. (I am a beginner btw so sorry if its a really easy mistake.)

```
if(finishAnt == "yes") {
                console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")   
            }
            else if(finishAnt == "no") {
                console.log("You run away and barley make it, you are badly hurt");
                } else {
                    console.log("sorry thats not an option")
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have an **odd** number of curly brackets.

Comment: just an extra `}` at the end. Try indenting your code correctly and it'd be obvious.

Comment: `"but it gets hazy of exactly were it is after that"` - The error doesn't *specify* a line number?  It really should.

Comment: If you formatted/indented your code properly, you'd be able to see it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}`

correct as

```
if(finishAnt == "yes") {
   console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")   
}
else if(finishAnt == "no") {
    console.log("You run away and barley make it, you are badly hurt");
} else {
    console.log("sorry thats not an option")
}
```